# IntelliJ Idea Play framework Twirl template formatting settings?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework-2.0, twirl

I'm pretty happy to use the IntelliJ Idea Ultimate 2016 as my primary IDE for Play Framework based projects (together with Scala), but I'm not happy with some default settings how Idea formats the Play's Twirl template files (e.g. indent size, comment formatting). However, I'm unable to find Twirl formatting settings anywhere in Idea prefs. Is the Twirl formatting setting page really missing in the IDE?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had been looking for the solution too. And I have finally found its indent settings.

It is Editor > Code Style > Other File Types.
I don't know comment formatting settings.

Thanks.